# google maps - get the coordinates of a dragged marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Im using this excellent jquery plugin for working with google maps:

http://googlemaps.mayzes.org/

Im using the "Map Marker Drag" example.

Once I have dragged a marker how can I get the new/current coordinates of the Marker?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any event binding in this plugin.I would suggest to use the google api and not a plugin since the api is equally easy to use.Also this plugin uses v2 api which is old and deprecated.You should migrate to google maps javascript api v3.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a project that does just this, it uses version 2 of Google Maps API.  Here is the snippet of code to make a draggable marker that will show lat/long after you drag it to a new place on map:

```
            function createMarker(latlng, number, html) {
                var marker = new GMarker(latlng, {draggable: true});
                marker.value = number;
                    var myHtml = html;
                    var center = marker.getLatLng();
                    map.openInfoWindowHtml(latlng, "<font color=black>" + myHtml + "<br>" + center.toString() + "</font>");
                GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragstart", function() {
                    map.closeInfoWindow();
                });
                GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
                    var center = marker.getLatLng();
                    marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<font color=black>" + myHtml + "<br>" + center.toString() + "</font>");
                });
                return marker;
            }
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant since the question is not asking for help on google maps api.

Comment: not directly. But the above mentioned script uses Google Maps API. and the easiest way to do what he wants to do is explained in this post.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this using javascript and google maps API:

```
// update element with latest lat and lon
function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('ll').value = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function initialize() {
  // look for any lat lon in url, to set map center
  if ($.urlParam('ll')) {
    var llparam = $.urlParam('ll').split(', ');
    var lat = parseFloat(llparam[0]);
    var lon = parseFloat(llparam[1]);
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  } else {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.65130629733119, -122.34994607543945);
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the markers .latLng() to get coordinates of any marker.